# tikz won't put drawings in correct coordinates

Tags: coordinates

```
\draw[very thick] (12.5,0) node[left] {Nature} -- (12.5,2);
```

That code there does not work, no matter what I put in for 12.5. It just stays put in the left part of the page.

Help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and complete your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tikz` (or `pgf`) uses the smallest rectangular box that encloses the points used in the image.  If you want the box to include e.g. the origin you can add a simple `\draw (0,0);` command:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0);
  \draw[very thick] (12.5,0) node[left] {Nature} -- (12.5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Alternative approaches include specifying the bounding box explicitly

```
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (12.5,2);
```

or moving the picture as a whole, e.g.

```
\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}
```

or using `\hspace{...}` (e.g. `\hspace{3cm}` before and/or after the picture.