# In TikZ, can I place the (0, 0) point myself?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It seems like the location of the origin depends on the dimensions of the pictures I am drawing. Is it possible to fix the location of the origin yourself, or otherwise to manipulate the location of the whole tikz box in some way?

**Minimal Example**

For example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) -- (-2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The origin in this picture seems not too far from the left of the page. However, changing the line above to

```
\draw (0, 0) -- (-10, 0);
```

shifts the origin to the right.

Comment: It is possible to define a bounding box which, depending on how it is defined, will place the origin at a specific point in that bounding box.

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at. A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem would really help.

Comment: @PeterGrill I have added a MWE.

Comment: Ti*k*Z always establishes its bounding box on the basis of the content of the picture. That's what you are seeing here. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349532/121799) for one of the many related questions.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `\noindent` _before_ `\begin{tikzpicture}`.  If you include `\usepackage{show frame}` you see that with the `\noindent` the picture is all the way to the left.

Comment: @Ovi You seem to think that `(0,0)` should be a point defined by a fixed offset from the paper edges or page margins, but this is not how it works. For this kind of positioning, read *Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning* in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). For normal positioning, the bounding box is essential; read section *Creating a Picture Using an Environment* or the link marmot gave, or [that one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495430/behavior-of-coordinates-when-using-tikz) for instance.

Comment: Thank you all for the information, I will get reading.

Comment: @frougon Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks, but not really. My opinion is that at this point, either the OP has read the information (the links I gave explain it in detail) or he or she is not motivated to get it. Feel free to write an answer if you are motivated enough, though...

Comment: @frougon I'm asking only to remove the question from the unanswered list

Comment: @CarLaTeX Right, but I wrote a lengthy explanation in the [other link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495430/behavior-of-coordinates-when-using-tikz) which only Sebastiano read, apparently, and I really don't feel like rewriting it just for the sake of removing a question from the unanswered list. My time is very limited and the OP didn't show any sign of life here for a long time, so...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sorry if I sound bitter. There are days like that... I'll write an answer if the OP is still interested.

Comment: @frougon Thanks a lot for the offer. However, I wrote this question before I really learned TikZ from the manual. I was just trying to put together bits and pieces, and I had some really "stupid" questions, like this one (by "stupid" i mean that once your learn TikZ properly, or learn how to use other commands in LateX to mess with the picutre, such questions become not very useful). I finished the big documnent that I was working on long ago anyway.

Comment: @frougon We can close the question as duplicate, then :)

Comment: @Ovio Usually we reply also to old questions, because they could be useful to future users, if not to the original OP. I'm very happy you learned TikZ!